# Are the arguments passed from a parent function to a closure running as a goroutine copied if the parent function is called inside a loop?

Tags: go

So I want to run a seperate goroutine for each github repository to fetch all of its PRs and send them to their respective channels and merge all those channels to consume all the PRs of different repos from a single channel.

This is the code snippet for that.

```
func (c *Client) FetchAllPRs() {
    c.GetRepos()
    c.GetGitData()
    c.ghCollector.SetSHAMap(c.shaMap)
    start := time.Now()

    logging.Debug("TOTAL REPOS ", len(c.repos))
    var channels []<-chan *sources.PRDetails
    for _, repo := range c.repos {
        channels = append(channels, c.ghCollector.GetPRNumbers(c.context, repo.Details))
    }

    sink := mergePRChannels(channels)
    count := 0
    for _ = range sink {
        count += 1
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    logging.Info(count, " took time: ", elapsed)
}

func mergePRChannels(outputsChan []<-chan *sources.PRDetails) <-chan *sources.PRDetails {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // make return channel
    merged := make(chan *sources.PRDetails)
    wg.Add(len(outputsChan))

    output := func(sc <-chan *sources.PRDetails) {
        for sqr := range sc {
            merged <- sqr
        }
        // once channel (square numbers sender) closes,
        // call `Done` on `WaitGroup` to decrement counter
        wg.Done()
    }

    for _, optChan := range outputsChan {
        go output(optChan)
    }

    // run goroutine to close merged channel once done
    go func() {
        // wait until WaitGroup finishes
        wg.Wait()
        close(merged)
    }()

    return merged
}
```

Now the responses from Github are paginated and the PR fetching goroutine runs a loop inside of it.

```
type PRDetails struct {
    RepoName string
    PR       githubv4.Int
}

// GetPRNumbers returns a channel of PR details
func (ghc *GithubCollector) GetPRNumbers(ctx context.Context, repo *RepoDetails) <-chan *PRDetails {

   // these two are just struct types representing the graphql request
    var fbreq firstBatchRequest
    var sbreq subsequentBatchRequest
    var hasNextPage githubv4.Boolean
    var cursor githubv4.String
    out := make(chan *PRDetails)
    go func(out chan *PRDetails, repoName string, fbreq firstBatchRequest, sbreq subsequentBatchRequest, hastNextPage githubv4.Boolean, cursor githubv4.String) {
       // graphql options
        opts := map[string]interface{}{
        }
        err := ghc.graphQLClient.Query(ctx, &fbreq, opts)
        if err != nil {
            close(out)
            return
        }

        if len(fbreq.Repository.PullRequests.Nodes) == 0 {
            close(out)
            return
        }

        for _, pr := range fbreq.Repository.PullRequests.Nodes {
            out <- &PRDetails{
                RepoName: repo.Name,
                PR:       pr.Number,
            }
        }
        hasNextPage = fbreq.Repository.PullRequests.PageInfo.HasNextPage
        cursor = fbreq.Repository.PullRequests.PageInfo.EndCursor

        // no more PRs after the first batch, return
        if hastNextPage == githubv4.Boolean(false) {
            logging.Debug("no next page", repoName)
            return
        }
        // loop till all the PR numbers have been collected
        for {
          // graphql options
            opts := map[string]interface{}{
            }

            // doesn't appear to be a valid cursor ``
            err := ghc.graphQLClient.Query(ctx, &sbreq, opts)
            if err != nil {
                break
            }

            for _, pr := range sbreq.Repository.PullRequests.Nodes {
                out <- &PRDetails{
                    RepoName: repo.Name,
                    PR:       pr.Number,
                }
            }
            cursor = sbreq.Repository.PullRequests.PageInfo.EndCursor
            if sbreq.Repository.PullRequests.PageInfo.HasNextPage == githubv4.Boolean(false) {
                break
            }
        }
    }(out, repoName, fbreq, sbreq, hasNextPage, cursor)
    return out
}
```

So what happens is that, it runs fine for the first request, that is it will fetch the first 100 PR numbers for all the repos but it never enters the for loop to get the next batch using the EndCursor returned by the Github API.

So I printed out a out for just one repo using its name in an if statement, to see if the `hasNextPage` value has been set to false which might be the reason for it to not enter the for loop but to my surprise the log printed out true and the it also went inside this if statement and returned

```
if hastNextPage == githubv4.Boolean(false) {
            // our channel already has values in it so we use a naked return without close
            logging.Debug("no next page", repoName)
            return
        }
```

it should not have done that, now I am thinking that all the arguments that I am passing to my goroutine closure are they copies or references that some other goroutine might be changing the true to false, which doesn't make any sense. Since this `c.ghCollector.GetPRNumbers`
 runs in a loop, so I assumed that everytime this function is called all the variables that are declared outside of the closure will be instantiated for every function separately and I won't need any mutexes to read or write. I am very confused, nothing makes sense.

What am I doing wrong here?

Also I am not sure if I should be passing the out chan to the closure  or not, it will probably work fine without it but my brain is fried

Here is a condensed example of the problem

```
func FetchAllPRs() {
    repos := []{"repoa", "repob"}
    for _, repo := range repos {
        channels = append(channels, GetPRNumbers(repo))
    }

    sink := mergePRChannels(channels)
    count := 0
    for _ = range sink {
        count += 1
    }

    fmt.Println(count)
}

func mergePRChannels(outputsChan []<-chan *PRDetails) <-chan *PRDetails {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    merged := make(chan *PRDetails)
    wg.Add(len(outputsChan))

    output := func(sc <-chan *PRDetails) {
        for sqr := range sc {
            merged <- sqr
        }
        wg.Done()
    }

    for _, optChan := range outputsChan {
        go output(optChan)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(merged)
    }()

    return merged
}

type Response struct {
    Cursor      string
    HasNextPage bool
}

func mockGithubResponse() {
    return &Response{
        Cursor: "fdsfdsfdsfsdfsfsdwrWfsdfs=",
        HasNextPage: true,
    }
}

type PRDetails struct {
    RepoName string
    PR       githubv4.Int
}

// GetPRNumbers returns a channel of PR details
func GetPRNumbers(repoName string) <-chan *PRDetails {
    var hasNextPage bool
    var cursor string
    var resp *Response
    out := make(chan *PRDetails)
    go func(repoName string, resp *Response, hastNextPage bool, cursor string) {
       // execute the graphql query and unmarshall the result in struct
       // for now using a mock reponse
       resp := mockGithubResponse()

        hasNextPage = resp.HasNextPage
        cursor = resp.Cursor

        // no more PRs after the first batch, return
        if hastNextPage == false {
            fmt.Println("no next page", repoName)
            return
        }
        // loop till all the PR numbers have been collected
        for {
          fmt.Println("if hasNextPage then enter the for loop")
          // get more PRs
        }
        close(out)
    }(repoName, resp, hasNextPage, cursor)
    return out
}
```

Comment: Could you come up with a short, minimal example of your problem?

Comment: @Volker I have removed some of the code can you take a lookt at it now?

Comment: Sorry, I really meant a synthetic example devoided of any business logic, runnable in the playground. Your question seems to be "Are the arguments passed from a parent function to a closure running as a goroutine copied if the parent function is called inside a loop?" and an example of _just_ this might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program

```golang
package main                                                                                                                                                                                                       

import "fmt"                                                                                                                                                                                                       

func main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  test("a", "b")                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  select {}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

func test(text1, text2 string) {                                                                                                                                                                                   
 go func(t1 string) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
  for {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    fmt.Println(t1, text2)                                                                                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 }(text1)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 text1 = "1"                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 text2 = "2"                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

produces from some point till end only

```
a 2
```

It shows that if you pass something to the closure by parameter it is separate variable. If you use the surrounding function variable it is not copied.